# how to get all the hours in gantt chart x axis for 1day case using d3

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, d3.js

```
I am using following code
          case "1day":
            format = "%H:%M";
```

gantt.timeDomain([d3.time.day.offset(getEndDate(), -1), getEndDate()]);
                break;
    to display hours on x axis gantt chart. in this case i am getting 0, 3,6 format. how can i display all the hours in x axis like 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5---